# Is "team e-mail" an idiomatic expression in native English?

Tags: idioms, email

Just as the title already suggests, could you please tell me if "team email" is something that natives actually use, especially in business environment?

The specific context: What is meant here by "team email" is a shared group mailbox used by all our team members, ie. this is the "outside" e-mail address provided to our customers, so that no matter at what time they send the e-mail, someone who's currently on the shift, will be able to see it.

Comment: I guess I'll edit my question so it's clearer what my company means by it. :)

Comment: OK, with the new question, I would probably prefer the term "team mailbox".  Or maybe the "customer mailbox".

Comment: How would you call the shared address then? Like what you put in your signature for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably understand what you meant  by “team email” from context, but the term I’d use is “shared mailbox”.

Normally, I’d expect “team email” to mean an email sent to the entire team such that each member received their own copy in their personal mailbox.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I felt natives would rather use too. However I'm not sure how fit such a term is for official business correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

It's not idiomatic. Generally the term email covers situations where you are either emailing a single person or a group as in

- email it to him
- email it to everybody

Whereas saying

- group email it to the group

Or

- team email it to the group

Just sounds unnecessarily long-winded.

Comment: OP has clarified that the expression is a noun referring to a group mailbox, not a verb. You may want to edit.